# Launch python file on server in objective-c

Tags: python, ios, objective-c

I'm working on an application, in which in need to launch a python file (ex : myPythonFile.py) on a server. I try to do :

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"www.myWebsite.fr/myPythonFile", 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried other thing, like add .py in the address to launch, but it doesn't work.

My application is in objective-C.

Does anyone have a solution ?